# Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' .Net Core 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 for my web application. It worked fine a couple days ago when I published it on my server. Now the application works fine on my local machine, but when I publish it on the server the application doesn't start. There is an error with a status code of 500 and when I look into the log file there is a following message:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'**

I haven't done any SDK upgrade neither in the application nor on my server. I tried cleaning up .dll files in my project and re-publishing it but didn't work.

Have you got any idea what should be wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you hosting? I'm guessing you don't have the correct version installed on server?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>    
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```